# How to set a quick weapon access key with a controller in Fallout: New Vegas on PC?

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

In **Fallout: New Vegas** on PC, you can set a quick weapon access keys by pressing a keyboard shortcut (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8), and clicking a weapon in the menu. The keys are replaced by directions on the direction pad when playing with a controller.
I am playing with a 360 controller, the keyboard commands are disabled. It is therefore tedious to modify the quick weapon access keys, since I have to disable my controller in the controls menu each time I want to do it.

Is there a less tedious method to set the quick weapon access keys when playing with a controller?

Comment: I assume setting the hotkeys using the controller itself doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: I found that it works when you keep `RightTrigger` pressed and then press one of the directions on the pad. Your comment helped me!

Comment: @wil [You can answer your own questions here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) You should probably post your comment (and mention Studoku's comment) as an answer.

Comment: @galacticninja Sure, and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Studoku suggested, it is possible to set the hotkey using the controller.
You have to keep the *Right Trigger* pressed, and then press one of the directions on the directional pad.